# How do you explicitly use a specific method when the method name is identical to another available method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am including two different module libraries in my class.  Both have the method `test_method`.  How do I explicitly use one over the other?

```
class User
include Calculus::Math #a module
include Algebra::Math::Misc #a module

#perform_test is defined in both Calculus::Math and Algebra::Math::Misc
perform_test: 1 

#Calculus::Math::perform_test: 1 #This doesn't work

end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a bit if meta programming:

```
(Calculus::Math).method(:perform_test).bind(self).call 1
```

or

```
include Calculus::Math
alias :foo :perform_test
include ...
```

I haven't tested either of these and might have made some small errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning `perform_test` into a module function on `Calculus::Math`.

```
Calculus::Math.module_eval do
  module_function(:perform_test)
  public :perform_test
end

class User
  include Calculus::Math #a module
  include Algebra::Math::Misc #a module

  Calculus::Math.perform_test(1)
end
```